# How can I use Chrome's Console Utilities API to set a breakpoint on a function inside a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

The [Console Utilities API reference](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/) discusses the [debug](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#debug-function) function. debug can set a breakpoint on the first line of a function just by entering `debug(aFunction)` in the console.

Let's say I have a vue app like [this](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kU1Lw0AQhv/KuJe0UBOkt5oWVCrqQUUFL3sJ6SRN3ewu+1ELIf/d2Y2tOUhvO+8HPLPTsRut071HtmC5LU2jHVh0Xq+4bFqtjIMODFbQQ2VUCwlFEy65LJW0DlpbwzL4k+QBhVDwqYzYXCTTEKm8LF2jJBT3v6/JFDouAUJZCUyFqieQFHBMJjC95rIP5VGHJC7zbKAjLhoctloUDmkCyLdXq66LLH2fZzRFtZHaO9hftmqDYskZ+ZxBRmaejfpsxpwloKqp051Vkj4iMnJWqlY3As2LDhyWs8VAH7yClv1+ipozHmdHvdxi+fWPvrOHoHH2atCi2SNnJ88VpkY32Ov3ZzzQ+2QSvReUPmO+IX2mD4xD7NbLDWGPcpH2MZ6zkfWHXR8cSntcKoCGZB/znNGJ786s/oc7T+exRydj/Q+mFMMn) one and I wanted to use `debug` to set a breakpoint on the function `aFunction`.

Attempting to enter `debug(aFunction)` in the console just results in the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: aFunction is not defined` being emitted.

I am guessing there is someway to reference `aFunction` inside of the component so `debug` can be used to set the breakpoint. If so, how?

Comment: the component functions aren't globally scoped, and exist inside the vue instance which I'm not immediately sure how you would access directly from console.  I would just add the line `debugger;` as the first line of `aFunction` for a very similar debug experience.

Comment: I was already aware of `debugger`. I am curious if using `debug` was possible. Perhaps the answer to this question is "It's Not Possible."